# Clear default option associate with email attachment

Tags: android

Here my question is not related with coding, I want to know that how to clear the default value that used to come with "Complete action using" dialog box.

Here I was running my application, click on button will redirect it to gmail application and click on any of the email attachement is showing 2 options "with complete action using" dialog box to preview this attachment.

Then by mistake, i select an option and set it as a default one.. Now everytime when I did opened any attachment from this gmail application, it is directly opening this attachment file into the previously default app, now it is showing the 2 options and "complete action using dialog box"..

So how can I clear these default values so that again it will show me that dialog box??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your device, go to Settings > Apps > (click on app) > Clear defaults. Or, on an emulator, just restart it with the "Wipe" checkbox checked to basically factory-reset it.